Failed installation of services from INF file Using the commandline
I wish to install the three services for the Windows User Mode Driver Foundation v1.9 using the commandline. Every command I have tried fails, yet if I right click on wudf_update.inf and select install the services install OK.  The successful command from the context menu can be found in the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\inffile\shell\Install\command and it's value is
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 %1

Based on this I have tried the command:
rundll32.exe setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 %SystemRoot%\INF\wudf_update.inf

but I receive the message "Installation Failed"
The following commands also fail:
rundll32.exe advpack,LaunchINFSection %SystemRoot%\INF\wudf_update.inf,DefaultInstall

rundll32 syssetup,SetupInfObjectInstallAction DefaultInstall %SystemRoot%\INF\wudf_update.inf

Here is the content of wudf_update.inf:
    [Version]
Signature = "$WINDOWS NT$"
Provider = %MSFT%
CatalogFile = wudf_update.cat
DriverVer=09/15/2005,1.0.0.0

; ****************************************************************************
;
; These two sections are run when Install is invoked on the INF
;
; ****************************************************************************

[DefaultInstall]

[DefaultInstall.Services]
AddService=WudfSvc,%NOCLOBBER_SERVICE%,WudfSvc_Install
AddService=WudfRd,%NOCLOBBER_SERVICE%,WudfRd_Install
AddService=WudfPf,%NOCLOBBER_SERVICE%,WudfPf_Install

; ****************************************************************************
;
; Install the driver manager service
;
; ****************************************************************************

[WudfSvc_Install]
DisplayName=%WUDFSVC_DISPLAY_NAME%
Description=%WUDFSVC_DESCRIPTION%
ServiceType=0x20
StartType=%SERVICE_DEMAND_START%
ErrorControl=0x01
ServiceBinary=%10%\system32\svchost.exe -k WudfServiceGroup
LoadOrderGroup=PlugPlay
Dependencies=PlugPlay
StartName = "LocalSystem"
AddReg=WudfSvc_Registry

[WudfSvc_Registry]
HKR, "Parameters", "ServiceDll", %REG_EXPAND_SZ%, "%SystemRoot%\System32\WUDFSvc.dll"
HKR, "Parameters", "ServiceDllUnloadOnStop", %REG_DWORD%, 1
HKR, ,             "FailureActions", %REG_BINARY%, 84,03,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,01,00,00,00,C0,D4,01,00,01,00,00,00,E0,93,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
HKR, ,             "ServiceSidType", %REG_DWORD%, 1

HKLM, "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\svchost", "WudfServiceGroup", 0x00010008, "WUDFSvc"

; ****************************************************************************
;
; Install the reflector service
;
; ****************************************************************************

[WudfRd_Install]
DisplayName=%WUDFRD_DISPLAY_NAME%
Description=%WUDFRD_DESCRIPTION%
StartType=%SERVICE_DEMAND_START%
ServiceType=0x1
ErrorControl=0x01
ServiceBinary=%12%\wudfrd.sys

; ****************************************************************************
;
; Install the platform service
;
; ****************************************************************************

[WudfPf_Install]
DisplayName=%WUDFPLATFORM_DISPLAY_NAME%
Description=%WUDFPLATFORM_DESCRIPTION%
StartType=%SERVICE_DEMAND_START%
ServiceType=0x1
ErrorControl=0x01
ServiceBinary=%12%\WudfPf.sys
LoadOrderGroup="base"

; ****************************************************************************
;
; Source of all files being copied.
;
; ****************************************************************************

[SourceDisksNames]

[SourceDisksFiles]

[SourceDisksFiles.IA64]

[SourceDisksFiles.AMD64]

; ****************************************************************************
;
; Destinations for each copy section.
;
; ****************************************************************************

[DestinationDirs]

;
; Substitution strings used in the INF
;

[Strings]
MSFT="Microsoft Corporation"

WUDFSVC_DISPLAY_NAME="Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework"
WUDFSVC_DESCRIPTION="Manages user-mode driver host processes"

WUDFRD_DISPLAY_NAME="Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework Reflector"
WUDFRD_DESCRIPTION="Reflect device requests to user-mode driver drivers"

WUDFPLATFORM_DISPLAY_NAME="Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework Platform Driver"
WUDFPLATFORM_DESCRIPTION="Provide communciation services for UMDF components."

NOCLOBBER_SERVICE=0x00000010
SERVICE_BOOT_START=0x0
SERVICE_DEMAND_START=0x3

REG_EXPAND_SZ=0x00020000
REG_SZ=0x00000000
REG_DWORD=0x00010001
REG_BINARY=0x00000001

The driver files have been copied to the correct location and wudf01009.cat has been copied to the correct location using signtool.  I am using Windows XP.

I lloked in setupapi.log and I am receiving the warning Add Service: Failed to get configuration of service "WudfSvc". Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified
